# iOS Slider Precision When Sliding Complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

My app has a simple slider placed on a view which allows the user to define their search radius. My problem is the precision of the slider when the user completes dragging and removes their finger from the display. The slider is pulling an extra 1-5 points in the direction it was sliding when the user is done.

So, if the original position was at '100' and the user drags to '10', when he removes his finger it slips to '7' or '8'.

The issue seems to be become increasingly problematic as I get to either end of the slider.

Any idea why this might be happening? I'd provide a code sample but again, this is just a simple UISlider on a UIView, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code here. Let me see what I can do. Please try this code it's working fine for me

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    // Set the label text to the value of the slider as it changes
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.slider.value];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is my code, essentially. It seems like a glitch in the UI, not so much a programmatic issue